# How to instatiate a 'typed' Map?

Tags: f#

I created a custom type which is implementing a `Map`.

```
type School = Map<int, string list>
```

I tried now various ways on how to instatiate that type but it always fails.
With attempt Nr.1 I thought maybe one can 'dot' the class (somehow).

```
let xyz = School.Map.empty;;
or
let kgse = School.empty;;
//The type 'Map<Key,Value>' does not define the field, constructor or member 'empty'.
```

Attempt Nr.2 was my hope that f# knows if I create a map which has the same structure of the custom type it assigns it automatically.

```
let xyz =
-   Map.empty.
-     Add(2, ["Alex"]);;
val xyz: Map<int,string list> = map [(2, ["Alex"])]
```

This works but it only returns the general `Map` class.
Finally, I thought maybe I can cast the type.

```
let xyz =
-   School Map.empty.
-     Add(2, ["Alex"]);;
```

This throw me again an error:
`Successive arguments should be separated by spaces or tupled, and arguments involving function or method applications should be parenthesized`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

F# have pretty neat feature - types with same name can extend each other. For example `System.Collection.Generic` have type `EqualityComparer` with static property `Default`, which return adequate comparer for given generic type, **but** it doesn't fit for collections, because they would be compared be reference, instead of by value.

In C# you can't write extensions for static class to call `EqualityComparer<T>.ForCollection`, but you can with F#:

```ml
module EqualityComparer =
    let ForCollection<'a> = ...

let def = EqaulityComparer.Default
let mine = EqualityComparer.ForCollection
```

As you can see, we extended `static class` with `module`. This is 2 distinct types with same name and we can use methods and properties from both.

Same happens with `Map` **class** and `Map` **module**. You've created alias for type which can be instantiated but haven't for helper module. What you need to do is create type abbreviation for module

```ml
type School = Map<int, string list>
module School = Map

School.empty
```

Comment: `module School = Map`: I didn't know you could do that. Very cool!

Comment: @brianberns strange that this feature is not listed in F# docs. I don't even know where I've found it

Comment: I couldn't find it either. Maybe it's unintentional?

Comment: @brianberns I doubt language can have *unintentional features*, especially this kind. Looks like it's for compatibility with ML

Answer (score 4):

Part of the problem here is that `School`, as you've defined it, is a [type abbreviation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/type-abbreviations), not a distinct type of its own. This means that it is simply another name for `Map<int, string list>`. That's a good light-weight approach, and still allows you to create your own `School.empty` value, if you want:

```ml
module School =
    let empty : School = Map.empty

let xyz = School.empty.Add(2, ["Alex"])
```

If, on the other hand, you actually want `School` to be a real type, you should consider defining it as a record or discriminated union instead:

```ml
type School =
    private MkSchool of Map<int, string list> with
        member this.Add(key, values) =
            let (MkSchool map) = this
            MkSchool (map.Add(key, values))

module School =
    let empty = MkSchool Map.empty

let xyz = School.empty.Add(2, ["Alex"])
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a `School` type annotation to `xyz`:

`let xyz : School = Map.empty.Add(2, ["Alex"])`

Using `dotnet fsi`:

```
> type School = Map<int, string list>
-
- let xyz : School = Map.empty.Add(2, ["Alex"]);;
type School = Map<int,string list>
val xyz : School = map [(2, ["Alex"])]
```

You can also create functions to return `School` and then use them as follows:

Again, in `dotnet fsi`:

```
> let makeSchool s : School = Map.empty.Add s
-
- let addStudent (school: School) student : School = school.Add student
-
- let xyz' = makeSchool (3, ["Betty"])
-
- let newStudent = (4, ["Charles"])
-
- let schoolWithNewStudentAdded = addStudent xyz' newStudent
- ;;
val makeSchool : int * string list -> School
val addStudent : school:School -> int * string list -> School
val xyz' : School = map [(3, ["Betty"])]
val newStudent : int * string list = (4, ["Charles"])
val schoolWithNewStudentAdded : School =
  map [(3, ["Betty"]); (4, ["Charles"])]
```